Call usemutation hook automatically when component loads
   const data = { userId, token };
      mutate(data, {
        onSuccess: (response) => {
         
          if (response.status === 200) {
            setClients(response.data.client); 
          }
        },
        onError: (error) => {
          console.error("Error fetching clients:", error);
        }
      });

//different component
 const fetchClientUrl = (data) => {
      console.log("Fetching clients...");
      return axios.post(`${import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL}/client/List`,data); 
    };

export const fetchClient = () => {
  return useMutation(fetchClientUrl); 
};

Hello all , i am a newbie tom transtack query and i have a doubt .can we call the usemutation call automatically whenever the component loads just similar to useeffect.every time when the page loads i need to pass session id and token to obtain list of posts

please use useQuery instead of useMutation

@haiquan0121 how can i pass data while using usequery

Example:

custom hook:

    const useGetStudentReportDetail = (data: any) => {
        const {
            data: studentReportDetail,
            isFetching: isGetStudentReportDetailFetching,
            isLoading: isGetStudentReportDetailLoading,
            refetch: refetchGetStudentReportDetail,
            error: errorGetStudentReportDetail,
            isError,
            isSuccess
        } = useQuery<any, any>({
            queryKey: ['useGetStudentReportDetail', [data]],
            queryFn: () => {
                return api(data.endpoint(data.data));
            },
            enabled: data.userId
        });
        return {
            studentReportDetail: studentReportDetail?.data || {},
            isGetStudentReportDetailFetching,
            isGetStudentReportDetailLoading,
            refetchGetStudentReportDetail,
            errorGetStudentReportDetail
        };
    };


component call:

    const { studentReportDetail } = useGetStudentReportDetail({
        endpoint: API_URLS.REPORT_STUDENT[selectedTab],
        selectedTab,
        data: {
            params: {
                page,
                limit: 30,
                user_id: studentId
            }
        }
    });

Now every time the component is mounted it will automatically call the api, and it will automatically call back every time the data passed to the custom hook useGetStudentReportDetail is changed
Note that you can still control the automatic call by props enabled - when it is false, the api call hook will not be performed and vice versa
